# How to change the button colour when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this set of buttons from A to Z when I click on the particular alphabet the brands related to that letter will pop up. I have tried the below code but it is applying for all the buttons when I click only one button. How do I solve it

```
let brandList = 'ABCEDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split("");

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        bgColor: ""
    }
}

getBrandSortData(){
    return(
        <div className="BrandPageList_AlphabetContainer">
            <button value="all" className="BrandPageList_AllButton" onClick={this.handleClick}>All</button>
            {brandList.map((item,index) =>
                {
                    let disbaled = !this.isBrandCharacterAvailable(item)
                    return(
                        <button
                            disabled= {disbaled}
                            value={item}
                            key={index}
                            block="BrandPageList_AlphabetButtons"
                            mods = {{enabled : !disbaled}}
                            onClick={this.handleClick}
                            style={{backgroundColor: this.state.bgColor}}
                        >
                            {item}
                        </button>
                    )}

            )}
        </div>
    )
}

handleClick = event =>{
    const brandValues = event.target.value
    if(brandValues === "all"){
        console.log()
        return this.setAllBrands()
    }
    else{
        let brandSortDataByCharacter = this.state.brandSortData[brandValues]
        this.setState({
            allBrands:
                {
                    [brandValues]: brandSortDataByCharacter
                },
            bgColor: "red"
        })
    }
}
```

This is the image[image]Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use "this" keyword to refer current element.

Comment: @AbhishekPratapSingh where should I use "this" keyword

Comment: another way i see is saving the state of each character as an object like `{A: false, B:true, C:false}`

Comment: yes some characters are disabled because it does not have any brands related to characters

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `event` object to determine what letter you clicked on, you can pass the letter to the click handler when you render it.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this. I'm using a functional component with hooks, since this is the recommended way, but you can do the same in a class component:

```
const Alphabet = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState();
  return (
    <div className='alphabet'>
      {'ABCEDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('').map(char => (
        <div 
          className={`letter ${char === active ? 'active' : ''}`}
          onClick={() => setActive(char)}>{char}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here's a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/rfu78t52/2/)